# Automatic respawn fastcgi process by nginx?

Tags: nginx, go, fastcgi

I am using nginx and running fcgi protocol using [golang's fcgi module](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/fcgi/). How can I respawn my fcgi process automatically by nginx ?

My nginx.conf looks like

> ```
> server {
>     listen 80;
>     server_name 127.0.0.1;
>     root /home/jdk2588/testdir;
>     index index.html;   
>     location / {
>         access_log  /home/jdk2588/KARMA/nginx/access.log;
>         proxy_pass_header Server;
>         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
>         proxy_redirect off;
>         proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
>         proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
>     }
>     location ~ /goapp {
>         include         fastcgi.conf;
>         fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9001;
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/FcgiExample#Spawning_a_FastCGI_Process)

> Unlike Apache or Lighttpd, Nginx does not automatically spawn FCGI
>   processes. You must start them separately.

So you'll need to use an OS facility to do that.

My favourite is [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) but there are lots of other ways of doing it.

There isn't a go way of restarting a process when it dies as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

i recommend to use uwsgi for managing fcgi processes. it is capable of spawning a amount of worker-processes ready for input and restart them when they die. highly configurable and easy to install and use.

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

i have the options worker-exec, spooler, processes, protocol, enable-threads and master set.